# 2-Coloring a tree with $2n$ vertices with additional constraint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, coloring

Suppose given a tree $\mathcal{T}$ with $n$ pair of vertices $V=\{(p_0,q_0),\dots,(p_n,q_n)\}$ . According to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) we know that any tree can be colored by $2$ colors. But my problem is as follow:

I want coloring $\mathcal{T}$ with 2 colors such that each pair $(p_i,q_i)$  has  different color. Are there any proof or paper that show us it's possible or not? Thanks.

Comment: I think that it is possible if and only if the distance between any pair $(p_i,q_i)$ is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a coloring exists if and only if the distance between any of the $(p_i,q_i)$ is odd. The distance between two vertices is the number of edges in a shortest path between them.

**Proof** Suppose that indeed all such distance are odd, and color the tree
$\mathcal{T}$. Take a path from $p_i$ to $q_i$, say $p_i,v_1,\ldots, v_k, q_i$. As the coloring of the tree is proper, $v_1$ has a different color than $p_i$, and $v_2$ has a different color than $v_1$, etc. As the path will have an odd number of edges, $k$ is even, and so $v_k$ has the same color as $p_i$ and $q_i$ has different color then $v_k$. So $p_i$ and $q_i$ have different colors.

Now suppose that the distance from $p_i$ to $q_i$ is even, and let $p_i,v_1,\ldots, v_k,q_i$ be the path connecting them with $k$ odd. Suppose that we have a proper coloring of the tree where $p_i$ and $q_i$ have different color. Then $v_1$ and $v_k$ must also have different colors. And $v_2$ and $v_{k-1}$ must also have different colors, etc. And $v_{(k-1)/2}$ and $v_{(k+1)/2+1}$ must also have different colors. But then there is no color that $v_{(k+1)/2}$ can have that is distinct from the colors of these last two vertices.

Comment: In other words: there is only one proper coloring of the tree up to swapping the colors, and so the coloring in this problem is possible if and only if that proper coloring happens to already have this extra condition.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Exactly

Answer (score 1):

It's in general not possible. Take the simple tree with one root $r$ and three child leaves $c_1,c_2,c_3$. If we take $V=\{(r,c_1),(c_2,c_3)\}$ we can't get a 2-coloring as you want. If $c_2$ and $c_3$ have a different color, $r$ - which is neighbor of $c_2$ and $c_3$ - needs a third color so that it works out.

Or do you have more constraints on the tree or on the set $V$?

Comment: I think that it is possible if and only if the distance between any pair $(p_i, q_i)$ is odd right?

Comment: It seems like a good criterion and I didn't find a counter example yet :)

Comment: I proved it in an answer :)